# Is there a way to auto silence the phone at a particular time?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, calendars, volume, silent

I want my WP8 phone (Lumia 920) to be in Silent mode on every Sunday from 9 to 11 AM and be released from it automatically or to a particular time when I am in a meeting, which could be in my Calender.

So is there a way to achieve this? something like that would integrate with my calender and set the phone to auto silence, to a particular meeting or  a series.

Comment: Perhaps not by particular time, but I understand you should be able to automate it a bit with NFC tags. This would require that you be allowed to place NFC tags in the areas you need them, and remember to tap them at the appropriate times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, the app is called Quiet Hours. You can set a Schedule and choose what volume to set to.

Comment: It would be useful to include details of where this setting is, and how to set it in your answer

Answer (score 5):

A feature called "Quiet Hours" has been introduced into the core operating system with the 8.1 update. You can trigger quiet hours manually, or automatically with a preset time (e.g. via a calendar event). A cool feature related to quiet hours is the concept of an "Inner Circle". This is a group of contacts, e.g. your significant other, who may  contact you regardless of your quiet hours setting.

You can access the new quiet hours feature via Settings → Quiet hours. For more details, wpcentral.com has a nice writeup with screenshots on [how to use the new features](http://www.wpcentral.com/how-set-quiet-hours-and-inner-circles-windows-phone-81).

Comment: Important note: Quiet Hours only works when Cortana is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this, and you cannot create an app to do this for you because there is not direct access from the API to communicate with the ringer/silencer. This is definitelly one of the drawbacks.